# react-native link can't find my MainApplication.java file

Tags: react-native

Every time I try to `react-native link` a new library, I get the same error message.  Here it is for react-native-video.

`rnpm-install info Linking react-native-video android dependency
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Me/Projects/myProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/companyName/appName/MainApplication.java'
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues`

The actual location of my MainApplication.java file is

```
./android/app/src/main/java/com/appName/MainApplication.java
```

The difference is that React Native Link is including "company name" in the path, which doesn't match my project.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

I looked over some topic and found solution, you can try with:

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver`

and then add your npm install package & react-native link again.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It works, One reason is, if you are trying to resolve modules using package.json file in your project folders, you will get this linking problem.  If you use this babel plugin, you will solve both linking and module resolve problems

Comment: i installed realm db and change the setting of mainapplication as per req but its throwing error app:debugjavawithkavac error what the solution

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty late to the party on this, but for future reference;

**TLDR: Adding another folder like so `java/com/companyName/AppName/` will fix your issue.**

After updating to the latest react-native I had this issue too. Your android path contains your apps ID so `com.test.app` path should be `android/app/src/main/java/com/test/app`.

Looking at your error message, its actually telling you where it's expecting the file to be;

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open `'/Users/Me/Projects/myProject/android/app/src/main/java/com/companyName/appName/MainApplication.java'`

If you create another folder like so `java/com/companyName/AppName/` you will be able to automatically link plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Another way I tried and it works for me:

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Then retry install your package:
ex: 

`npm install react-native-image-picker@latest --save`

Then react-native link your package

`react-native link react-native-image-picker`

Answer (score 0):

There are only two options that i am aware of to solve this problem

1. close all the terminals to stop the node server running on a difference terminal.

   - If you still have the mistake after that then try the following option
     You might still have the error because you uninstall and re-install `react-native` without paying attention to the version that you installed which for most case will be the latest version. So double check the current version of your `react-native` when installing it. "\n"
2. so either

   - in your `package.json` you add `"react-native": "^0.60.5"` if the version is 0.60.5 replace "^0.60.5" by the version you are trying to run, in `devDepencies` and `run npm install` 
                            or
   - `run npm install react-native@0.60.5`  or `npm install react-native@version`