# React-native link path incorrect

Tags: java, react-native, react-native-linking

I have an app which fails on linking/unlinking packages, similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084162/react-native-link-cant-find-my-mainapplication-java-file).

It specifically fails on linking the `MainApplication.java` file with this error.

> error Something went wrong while unlinking. Reason ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './AppName/android/app/src/main/java/co/AppName/AppName/MainApplication.java'

The path is actually incorrect `java/co/AppNAme` should be `java/com/AppName`.

I can't find anywhere what could be causing this or any documentation on how to set the path.

I've tried using `babel-plugin-module-resolver` but no success, unless im missing something. Anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** Adding another folder like so `java/co/AppNAme/AppName/` will fix your issue.

After updating to the latest react-native I had this issue too. Your android path contains your apps ID so `com.test.app path` should be `android/app/src/main/java/com/test/app`.

You've stated;

> The path is actually incorrect `java/co/AppNAme` should be `java/com/AppName`.

This isn't correct as looking at your error message, its actually telling you where its expecting the file to be;

> no such file or directory, open `java/co/AppName/AppName/MainApplication.java`

If you create another folder like so `java/co/AppNAme/AppName/` it will fix your issue.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, I didn't realize that the app ID and path was connected. Thanks! Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your project and then see whether after renaming the project the path is correct or not.

You may also try giving manual path or add the folder where it searches by default let's say com.company.name